# Postgres Full-Text Search: Phrase Operator (<x>) distance is looking for an exact distance match

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, full-text-search, amazon-rds, tsvector

When doing full text search using the phrase operator (`<X>`) syntax, it's not doing "less than or equal to" the number, as I would expect.  The search value must be exactly that many positions away.

Given this example:

```
select *
from (values
  ('bob is really smart, isn''t he?')
) docs(body)
where
  to_tsvector(body) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'bob <3> smart');
```

Using `<3>` returns the match.  However, any other larger value (i.e. `<4>` or `<5>`) does not match.

Is there some configuration setting in Postgres for the use of the tie-fighter?

I'm using an RDS Postgres instance on AWS: `PostgreSQL 9.6.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit`

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that it's functioning as intended. :/

There used to be an `AROUND(X)` function that does as I would expect it to (*less than or equal to*), but it looks like it was removed from Postgres at some point.

There are some patches available that create a `<X, Y>` syntax, where `X` is the minimum distance and `Y` is the maximum distance. These are not viable within the context of an RDS instance on AWS.

- [Range phrase operator in tsquery (V1 Patch)](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20180427140307.038769f4@asp437-24-g082ur)
- [Range phrase operator in tsquery (V2 Patch)](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20180709150905.6a27d15c%40asp437-ThinkPad-L380)
- [Some AROUND(X) examples](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20171013163732.1bb85695%40PostgresPro-A-Chernyshov)

Comment: Thanks for the self-answer, I was looking for this. I guess for now a workaround for small distances is to codegen the query...:

```'(bob <1> smart) | (bob <2> smart) | (bob <3> smart)'```

Comment: I don't think `AROUND` function ever actually got into Postgres. It was suggested, but then dropped in favor of this range phrase operator, which never got in either...

Comment: A better way to track this unfinished range phrase operator: https://commitfest.postgresql.org/21/1624/